# Random Variable PDF with coin tosses.

Tags: probability-distributions

Hello I am trying to figure out a few parts of the following question:

We consider a random selection of coins where the probability of heads, C for the coins is a random variable whose pdf is $ f_c = k*c $ for $ 0 \leq c \leq 1  $.

a) Find k.

For this part I integrate $f_c$ from $ \infty $ to $ -\infty$ and set it equal to 1 and solve for k. I get 2.

b). Find P(H) for a single coin toss.

I am having trouble understanding what this part means. My understanding is that the $ f_c $ is distribution of different possible probabilities for a head. I don't see how to generalize this to a get a single probability.

Comment: "We consider a random selection of coins where the 'probability of heads, C for the coins is a random variable' ... " - What does this mean?

Comment: I am not sure that is what I have trouble understanding.